Entire screen freezes randomly, system seems to function otherwise
I just started encountering this issue where seemingly if I do anything too intense, my screen stops updating. Audio persists, and I can still alt tab and that switches between apps fine. So it’s seems like the computer is still totally functioning, except I just can’t see anything move. Not even mouse.
I only recently had this start happening. I tried Sudoku which worked for a good 40 minutes, and if I set my display scale to 1920-1080 seems like I could play Getting Over It with Bennett Foddy for longer than I could otherwise, but this issue just occurred right after I set it back to 4k. So I suspect it might have something to do with display?
For some background, my computer is an HP Spectre x360 15t Convertible with Windows as the main partition. I also have mainly used linux to experiment with LibTAS, and I was recently trying to test different versions and used a purge command to try and make sure nothing lingered from another version. I suspect that command might have done something but I am not familiar with Linux enough to know certainly. Any help appreciated!
Edit: I have 22.04 Jellyfish, installed it with rufus a couple years ago. As for karel’s comment, my screen just freezes. Not flashes or any of that nonsense.

You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details for us to actually provide help with. If you want Linux support, you should be asking at SE Unix & Linux as this site is Ubuntu only. I can think of many potential reasons for issues; but without knowing what you're actually using & how it was installed; we'd only be guessing anyway as to your configuration. We cannot rule out user procedural issues either, as you've provided no specifics.

This question is similar to: Screen suddenly flashes, becomes grainy and shows visual artifacts. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

since your computer is a laptop, there are limited things we can suggest you try regarding the hardware - you can't exactly unplug the graphics card or fit a replacement power supply.
the first question is: assuming your laptop is set up to dual boot either Windows or Ubuntu, do you observe the screen disruption when booting the other operating system? if there is disruption with both, then it is highly likely a hardware issue. apart from unplugging memory SIMMs (if the memory can be unplugged) there is not much else you can do.
if the screen disruption is specific to just Ubuntu, you can try rolling back to an earlier kernel to see if this helps. another thing to try is booting from a live Ubuntu USB flash drive, and see if there is screen disruption there. often with a live USB flash drive the kernel and many other parts of Linux on the drive are earlier versions that are only updated after Linux has been installed. hence you are effectively running an older kernel, etc.

Windows doesn’t do it, only ubuntu.

"Windows doesn’t do it, only Ubuntu": in that case you could try a different flavor of Linux - there could be something Ubuntu is doing that simply is not supported by your laptop. Mint XFCE may be a good starting point, it is based upon Ubuntu but sufficiently different that it may avoid the problems you are seeing.

I have used it for quite a while without noticing this issue, maybe it’s just when too much graphical overhead is there. I think I’ll just try and avoid using higher resolution display scale while doing anything fairly intense, since I’m mostly interested in TASing Flash games.
